# Solving a Complex Number polynomial problem

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

This is an example Complex equations problem, everything is well understood except **--(ii)** in the below solution. Please can anyone explain, how anyone could have guessed the expansion in **(ii)** of the polynomial equation using **(i)**.

$$\text{if } x= -5 + 2\sqrt{-4 }  \text{ ; find the value of : }  x^4+ 9x^3+35x^2-x+4$$

$$\text{Solution: } x +5 = 4i$$
$$\Rightarrow (x+5)^2= 16i^2$$
$$\Rightarrow (x+5)^2= -16$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2+10x+25= -16$$
$$\Rightarrow x^2+10x+41= 0 \Rightarrow(i)$$

$$\text{now, } \ x^4+ 9x^3+35x^2-x+4 $$
$$= x^2(x^2+10x+41)-x(x^2+10x+41)+4(x^2+10x+41)-160 \Rightarrow(ii)$$
$$= x^2(0)-x(0)+4(0)-160$$
$$=-160$$

$$\text{Therefore, the value of the polynomial for } x=-5 + 2\sqrt{-4 } \text{ is }   -160$$

Comment: The last equation you have written down is certainly nonsense.

Comment: @gerry, I have just corrected the final result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step ii was done by long division: the polynomial $x^4 + 9x^3 + \ldots$ was divided by $x^2 + 10 x + 41$ to get $x^2 - x + 4$, with a remainder of $-160$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be they simply divided with residue the two polynomials:

$$x^4+9x^3+35x^2-x+4=(x^2+10x+41)(x^2-x+4)-160$$